# How to give value of textbox to ngModel textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is my first html textbox with javascript code

```
<div>
<input type="text" onchange="getTheValue(this)" id="12345" />
</div>
```

and this is my second html tag

```
<input type="hidden" id="12345_hiddenField" ng-model="hiddenField"/>
```

And on `onchange` event  i am calling this  javascript function

```
function getTheValue(data) {
document.getElementById("12345_hiddenField").value = data.value;
}
```

i want first textbox value to be assigned to second textbox `ngmodel` value with pure javascript no angualrjs methods in that, becoz that `onchange` function is written in seperate pure javascript file,is their anyway to do this?

Comment: What if i told you you don't need an `onChange` method ? Is that ok for you ?

Comment: You can remove the `ng-model` tag from the second `input` field.

Comment: yes its ok, all i need is that eventually i want that first textbox value to be assigned to ngmodel value and even it should watch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this.

```
 document.getElementById("12345").addEventListener('change',function() {
 document.getElementById("12345_hiddenField").value = document.getElementById("12345").value;
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9fh8rxck/

Comment: is their anyway to add that value to ngmodel?

Comment: document.getElementById("12345").setAttribute("ng-model", "YourValue") But ofcourse i don't know if ng-model is visible when rendered to html. So I would suggest that you use a data-value in your html input like this.
<input type="hidden" id="12345_hiddenField" ng-model="hiddenField" data-value="empty"/> and then you document.getElementById("12345_hiddenField").setAttribute("data-value", "YourValue")

Comment: is their anyway to watch that 'data-value'?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by watch? You can always right-click on your site and select "Inspect Element" and then locate your hidden field in the html, here you can watch the data-value. Btw. you can call it whatever you want, just as long as you call i data- , so it could be data-tempvalue or data-myvalue etc. But if you want to get the value then you just say document.getElementById("12345_hiddenField").getAttribute("data-value");

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" ng-model="textboxValue" id="12345" />`

and your hidden:

`<input type="hidden" id="12345_hiddenField" value="{{textboxValue}}"/>`

Your input text is bound to the `$scope` property `textboxValue`

Your hidden input uses that variable as value `{{textboxValue}}`, everything is 2-way data-bound.

Comment: but i should not have  that first textbox in angualrjs format, instead second textbox has angularjs code, what i want is value inside of textbox changes i want to watch that and assign it to ngmodel

Comment: The function you're calling, is it within a separate js file ? Is it within angularjs ?

Comment: the function which i am calling is pure javascript file